# openSSL CLI encryption using AES-256-CBC

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

Dear openSSL enthusiasts,

I have questions about encryption using openSSL.

1. Let's say I have "secret-password" and salt='00000000' (which is in hex equivalent to '3030303030303030') and I want to use pbkdf2 with 10000 iterations and sha256 hashing that will be used in aes-256-cbc. In order to get (key, iv) pair out of it I do the following:

```
$ openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -a -k "secret-passphrase" -S 3030303030303030 -P
salt=3030303030303030
key=4308510484954F2C45965C7EE57655A016261037628F8E25E0C44B746217B805
iv =A1B59BE16D6AABD8C7B953E4D7D7514B
```

2. Now let's say I want to encrypt '0000000000000000'

```
$ openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -a -k "secret-passphrase" -S 3030303030303030 -v <<< '0000000000000000'
bufsize=8192
U2FsdGVkX18wMDAwMDAwMBqMQ8GU/iXU+NBj3NT6lF72hdiq/vECsiGIyk6gzC3S
bytes read   :       17
bytes written:       65
```

3. Now step 2 using (key, iv) from step 1.

```
$ openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -K '4308510484954F2C45965C7EE57655A016261037628F8E25E0C44B746217B805' -iv 'A1B59BE16D6AABD8C7B953E4D7D7514B' -base64  -v <<< '0000000000000000'
bufsize=8192
GoxDwZT+JdT40GPc1PqUXvaF2Kr+8QKyIYjKTqDMLdI=
bytes read   :       17
bytes written:       45
```

Decryption works correctly in both cases:

```
$ openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -K '4308510484954F2C45965C7EE57655A016261037628F8E25E0C44B746217B805' -iv 'A1B59BE16D6AABD8C7B953E4D7D7514B' -base64  -v <<< 'GoxDwZT+JdT40GPc1PqUXvaF2Kr+8QKyIYjKTqDMLdI='
bufsize=8192
0000000000000000
bytes read   :       45
bytes written:       17
```

and

```
$ openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -a -k "secret-passphrase" -S 3030303030303030 -v <<< 'U2FsdGVkX18wMDAwMDAwMBqMQ8GU/iXU+NBj3NT6lF72hdiq/vECsiGIyk6gzC3S'
bufsize=8192
0000000000000000
bytes read   :       65
bytes written:       17
```

**Q1.** Why results of steps 1-2 and step 3 are not the same?

**Q2.** Can I control "bytes written" length? If yes, how?

**Q3.** If the message to be encrypted is not equal in size to input buffer then how it is adjusted? What bytes are added if this is the case? Padding by zero bytes?
When I use 15 '0' then I have 16 bytes read, like below (I tried to enforce 16-bytes bufsize but it seems 80 is minimum). Those two below differ by "nopad" option. Why? Isn't here 16-byte multiple under the hood?

```
$ openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -a -k "secret-passphrase" -S 3030303030303030 -v -bufsize 16 -nopad <<< '000000000000000'
bufsize=80
U2FsdGVkX18wMDAwMDAwMBXbmH9q6kra/uzuL4MARoY=
bytes read   :       16
bytes written:       45

$ openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -a -k "secret-passphrase" -S 3030303030303030 -v -bufsize 16 <<< '000000000000000'
bufsize=80
U2FsdGVkX18wMDAwMDAwMBXbmH9q6kra/uzuL4MARoaVlPlc2JL/k6Rdp00EQK8N
bytes read   :       16
bytes written:       65
```

**Q4.** Message to be encrypted is 16-byte in length in the example above. Why "bytes read" is 17?
It seems 15 '0' are counted like 16-bytes. Maybe eol is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1. Why results of steps 1-2 and step 3 are not the same?

The first example includes the OpenSSL header that provides the salt:

```
$ echo U2FsdGVkX18wMDAwMDAwMBqMQ8GU/iXU+NBj3NT6lF72hdiq/vECsiGIyk6gzC3S | base64 -D | xxd
00000000: 5361 6c74 6564 5f5f 3030 3030 3030 3030  Salted__00000000
00000010: 1a8c 43c1 94fe 25d4 f8d0 63dc d4fa 945e  ..C...%...c....^
00000020: f685 d8aa fef1 02b2 2188 ca4e a0cc 2dd2  ........!..N..-.
```

The second doesn't have the header since you give the raw values. But it is the same encrypted payload, as you expected:

```
$ echo GoxDwZT+JdT40GPc1PqUXvaF2Kr+8QKyIYjKTqDMLdI= | base64 -D | xxd
00000000: 1a8c 43c1 94fe 25d4 f8d0 63dc d4fa 945e  ..C...%...c....^
00000010: f685 d8aa fef1 02b2 2188 ca4e a0cc 2dd2  ........!..N..-.
```

> Q2. Can I control "bytes written" length? If yes, how?

This question is unclear. Obviously you can write a different number of bytes if you have a different size payload. For a given payload and a given set of parameters, it will always be the same.

Note that the number of bytes written is the actual number of bytes OpenSSL output, not the number of bytes in the encrypted payload. In your example, 45 represents the number of bytes in the Base64-encoded output, plus a newline. If you remove the `-base64`, the bytes written will be 32 (2 blocks).

(As a side note, `-bufsize` is not relevant to the encryption process. It is the I/O buffer size, and is for tuning performance and memory usage.)

> Q3. *Basically, "how is padding done?"*

OpenSSL (and most systems) use the [PKCS#7 algorithm](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652#section-6.3) (sometimes called PKCS#5, for historical reasons).

The padding value is the number of padding bytes. So if 1 byte of padding is required, the padding is "01". If 2 bytes of padding, it's "02 02". If no padding is required, an extra block of 0x10 bytes is added (i.e. sixteen copies of 16, which is the blocksize). This means that you can only fit 15 bytes into a single block with padding. A 16 byte payload requires 2 blocks with padding, which sometimes surprises people.

This padding is preferred because it is unambiguous. You can always read the last byte and remove that number of padding bytes. You can then detect if the decryption was successful by checking that all of the bytes removed have the same value. (This is a somewhat weak check, and fails approximately 0.5% of the time by chance, but in many systems is the only way the system checks that the password was correct.)

> Q4. Why "bytes read" is 17?

Given this line:

```
$ openssl ... <<< '0000000000000000'
```

You're using a [here-string syntax](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) (probably from zsh). That is documented to:

> Perform shell expansion on word and pass the result to standard input. This is known as a here-string. Compare the use of word in here-documents above, where word does not undergo shell expansion. **The result will have a trailing newline after it.**

So your input is sixteen "0" characters followed by a newline, which is 17  bytes.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
$ echo -n '0000000000000000' | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -a -k "secret-passphrase" -S 3030303030303030 -v
bufsize=8192
GoxDwZT+JdT40GPc1PqUXuE33FyWfCN+0L4c8+GN5Bc=
bytes read   :       16
bytes written:       45
```